# Bypass daily limits with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, instagram, instagram-api

I have selenium code that helps me send automated messages via Instagram on the web.

The thing is after about 200 - 250 DM's at a stretch the browser give me an error `Something went wrong` and I can't access the `textarea`  element for sending the message.

I read some articles saying there's a daily limit to the amount of dm's that can be sent in a day, meanwhile I'm looking at sending about 1000+ messages at a stretch.

I'm sorry if my question seems off or there's no code but I'm genuinely curious to know if there's a way I can send about 1000 messages continuously at a stretch with selenium or are there API's that can be used to send dm's through the `requests` library

Comment: Standard answer to any "why does my scraper/Selenium tool not work?" question: contact the site and ask if there is an API you can use. I haven't looked, but for a site as large as Instagram I imagine there will be. And yes, you will quite probably have to pay $$$ for the privilege. It may also be worth checking Instagram's Terms of Service: again, I haven't checked myself, but I wouldn't be surprised if use of scrapers and/or Selenium against their site violates their ToS.

Answer (score 0):

On reviewing the [**Instagram**](https://www.instagram.com/) [Terms of Use](https://help.instagram.com/581066165581870/?helpref=uf_share) haven't noticed any rate limit restrictions. However when using a automation tool like *Selenium* there are a couple of SOPs to avoid getting [detected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62520191/7429447). Some of the SOPs emphasized in the article [Instagram Limits & Rules per Hour and Day (2022)](https://thepreviewapp.com/instagram-limits/#:%7E:text=Combined%20actions%20in%20total%3A%20500,20%2D50%20DMs%20per%20day.) are as follows:

- *Go slower*: Don’t do too many actions too fast.
- *Space out the Instagram tasks*: Try to divide your Instagram time into tasks and set your own Instagram limits.
- *Use your account regularly*: If you are having a new account try to use your account regularly with would show to Instagram that you act like a human, not a bot doing a lot of actions all at once.
- *Do not use third party apps*: Many of the apps and websites out there do not follow Instagram’s Rules and Policies. You might have logged into them, which means that they could have access to your Instagram password. Using them may put your account in danger of being blocked.